# TCP and UDP implementation of virtual terminal access

Tags: networking, routes

Im trying to understand the virtual terminal access. I was wondering if anyone know any sources for the Virtual Terminal Access protocol. And other sources like ftp, http, and remote procedure calls.

Comment: Most of the protocol specifications you list are available as public standards (though "remote procedure calls" covers a myriad of sins), e.g. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616

Answer (score 0):

**The [RFC Sourcebook](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/default1101.htm)...**

I'm not sure about the 'Virtual Terminal Access Protocol' though. That's a new one to me. Usually, if you're looking to communicate with a terminal you have to know the model of the specific terminal because there are so many different terminal specifications.

The RFC sourcebook, at the least, will give you a great resource to help implement FTP, HTTP,and RPC.

If you want to see a great example of a virtual terminal check out [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you meant the [Virtual Terminal Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_terminal) that was part of the ISO protocol stack.  It was never widely deployed.  The logical Internet equivalent was [telnet](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc854.html#b), which, while extremely useful in its day, was insecure and has since been replaced by [ssh](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4251.txt).